# How can  I get an image to appear then fade out then fade into home page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to Jquery and I believe it is required to do what I need to do here.

A client wants their home page to begin with only the logo image visible and then fade into the navigation and content of the home page after a second or so. The logo image would appear in the center (vertical and horizontal).  At the same time while the logo is shown the home page to appear in the background as a grey scale.

Comment: ... and the question is?

Comment: @Robert Taylor The question is to provide some example, jsfiddle or so

Comment: No, it's not required to use Jquery, but it will certainly make things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an image on top of everything else. This can be done by making the position: absolute, and maybe adjust the z-index. Give the image and id.

You can chain animate() functions and put whatever effect you want in there.

```
$( "#block1" ).animate({opacity: 100%;},1000).animate({opacity: 0%;},1000);
```

Because after the animation you want to remove the image so that it isn't displayed (or you can't click on anything underneath the image).

So can use toggle instead of animate (but toggle also adjusts height and width as part of its effect):

```
$( "#block1" ).toggle(1000);
```

To make only the image display initially, put everything else inside a div, and set it to display: none in css. Then set a callback ( .toggle( [duration] [, callback] ) at http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). And for the callback declare a function to set the display back on for everything else:

```
$( "#block1" ).toggle(1000, function () {
  $("#everythingelse").css("display: inline");
});
```

Or you can set the display to none with an animate function:

```
$( "#block1" ).animate({opacity: 0%;},1000,"linear", function () {
  $( "#block1" ).css("display: none");
  $("#everythingelse").css("display: inline");
});
```

With animate (more information at http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you have more custom control over its effects

Answer (score 0):

use a callback function inside animate function, look at this tutorial ... http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/